# Template from ThemeForest in datepicker - unable select date before today

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bought a template from themeforest and in any datepicker I can't 
select a date before today. I can't find any code who blocks or range
this control.

In my `inline.cs` I only have:

```
$('input.datepicker').datePicker({

    clickInput: true,
    startDate: '01/01/1995'
});
```

Comment: If you give me your website URL i'll take a look. I'm quite familiar with the plugin

Answer (score 1):

The code for the datepicker is probably in another file and is then made available as a jQuery plugin. In this file you'll find the restriction. Take a look at your  tags in your html to figure out where this code might be.